# Random number generator

Tags: random, numbers, generator, modulus

I wanted to create a simple program which would generate random numbers between 0 and 1.

```
double x2, x3, z0, z1;
int i = 0;
double x0 = 0.3453;
double x1 = 0.3894;

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    x2 = (x0 + x1)%1.0;
    x3 = (x1 + x2)%1.0;
    [...]
```

There is something wrong with line "x2 = ..." and "x3 = ..."
I'm getting an error: "invalid operands of types 'double' and 'double' to binary 'operator%'

Comment: Assuming that Marc's answered the question, you can help other users by clicking the accept (green checkmark) next to it.  It helps others with the same question find the right answer, and it helps eliminate questions marked as unanswered - so that people looking to help answer questions can find those that still need assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `%` modulo operator is for integer values only. If you want to take the modulo of floating point values, you have to use [fmod()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fmod.html) instead